# Record RTSP audio stream G.726 without transcoding

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, gstreamer, rtsp, live555

I receive live stream from ip camera (via rtsp) with video H264 and audio G.726. I need to store the stream in file (mp4 preferably) without transcoding. Video is recorded, but seems that ffmpeg cannot write G.726 nor to mp4 neither to other containers I've tried, like avi, mkv, ogg and so on.

> ffmpeg -i rtsp:... -vcodec copy -acodec copy test.mp4

Here is audio stream info:

> Stream #0:1: Audio: adpcm_g726le, 8000 Hz, mono, s16, 16 kb/s

Error:

> Could not find tag for codec adpcm_g726le in stream #0, codec not
>   currently supported in container

Also I tried live555 and GStreamer, but no success with audio stream.

Is there any possibility to record G.726 with no transcoding? If there is any C/C++ lib that can do this, point me please to it.

**Update**. Solution with Gstreamer for mkv:

> gst-launch-1.0 -e rtspsrc location=rtsp:... name=rtspsrc ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! matroskamux name=mux ! filesink location="test.mkv" rtspsrc. ! rtpg726depay ! mux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FFmpeg can mux the LE variant of G726 into two audio-only containers, not counting a raw dump.

Sun AU

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp:... -vcodec copy -an video.mp4 -acodec copy -vn audio.au
```

or

Apple IFF

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp:... -vcodec copy -an video.mp4 -acodec copy -vn audio.aiff
```

Comment: If I want to play these files, can the streams be synchronized? And another question, is it possible to mux the files in one container after they've been recorded?

Comment: If there were dropped audio packets, then no. I'd suggest transcoding the audio losslessly.

Comment: In case of transcoding, which audio codec is more preferable? Considering I have low cpu and memory resources.